# Directories rendered as packages in Intellij Idea 13?

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

After a rebuild of my android project i saw that the `src` folder and other folders(`assets`, `libs` etc) have turned into packages.(Packages in Intellij have a folder icon with a ball inside it)

Due to this, I also got errors in all files inside `src` folder. (for example see `SearchActivity.java` , 1st line).

[image]

I am new to Intellij so apologies if this sounds rudimentary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the Shopper folder has been set to being a source root, instead of the `src` folder. To fix, turn off Flatten Packages and Compact Empty Middle Packages, right-click on `src`, go to Mark Directory As, and then Sources Root. Then un-mark the project folder.

You can also do this from Project Settings.

Comment: Nice touch with the last paragraph that it's possible to do so in Project Settings (it's called Project Structure though in IntelliJ 2017.2.3) :)
Learned something new today as well, ty!

Answer (score 6):

As of 2019.2.2, it's easiest to do `File > Project Structure...`, double click `Modules`, and then under the "Sources" tab right click the folder and un-mark it as a source folder.